# Why does DHT hash the filenames?

Tags: hash, hashtable, p2p, dht

One of the objectives of DHT is to partition the keyspace, so each node (or group of them) has a share of it. To do so, it hashes the filename of a file that wants to be saved and stores it in the node responsible of this part of the network. But, why does it have to hash the filename? Couldn't it just work like a dictionary, so instead of having a node hold hash values between 0000 and 0a2d, it would hold filename values between C and E?

Answer (score 2):

> But, why does it have to hash the filename?

It doesn't have to be a filename. It can hash other things too. E.g. file contents. Or metadata. Or cryptographic keys used as identities of users in the network.

> Couldn't it just work like a dictionary, so instead of having a node hold hash values between 0000 and 0a2d, it would hold filename values between C and E?

Because filenames are not uniformly distributed throughout the possible keyspace (how often do you see filenames starting with some exotic unicode character?) and their entropy is spread over a variable length, leading to even more clustering at the top level.
If you were to index all existing unix filesystems in the world you would have massive clustering around the `/etc/...`  prefix for example.

There are other p2p network overlays that can deal with heavy clustering in the keyspace, often by rearranging the nodes around the hotspots to increase network capacity in regions of the affected keyspace, e.g. based on levenshtein distance, but they generally aren't *distributed **hash** tables* because they do not employ hashing.

Answer (score 0):

because searches are done on numbers.

When you hash a file, you end up with a number, and that number will be allocated in the nearest K-buckets of the nearest K-peers.

names are irrelevant, you're performing XOR searches on numeric spaces, so that you always search half of the space on every hop.

once you find a peer that has the bucket pointed by the hash, then you can communicate with that peer and exchange related information.

A DHT, like libtorrent's kademlia implementation has to be seen more of a distributed routing data structure. The problem you're solving is how do I find a number among billions of numbers, how do I find a peer among millions in the least amounts of hops possible, and the answer is that every node on the network has to follow a set of simple rules as to how to organize the numbers they're storing, and the peers that they know about.

I recommend you read these notes on how a real DHT actually works.
https://gist.github.com/gubatron/cd9cfa66839e18e49846

Also, storing a number takes a lot less space than storing a word.

If you know the word, you can hash the word and search for the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could work like a dictionary. However, it would be missing some desirable (for the typical DHT use case) emergent properties that come from using a hash.

One property that hashing (along with XOR distance metric) gives you is an even distribution of content amongst all the nodes participating in a DHT. "Even" here being caveated by how the k-bucket data structure works (here's an overview [k-bucket slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/11qGZlPWu6vEAhA7p3qsQaQtWH7KofEC9dMeBFZ1gYeA/edit?pli=1#slide=id.g1718cc2bc_0661)), but in aggregate, you get nodes evenly distributing data amongst the DHT peers.. in theory. In practice, you can get hotspots.

Another property of using a hash is if you're looking for a file with specific contents. So, if you use hashes of the file contents as the identifiers, you can be... statistically sure (the guarantee comes from your hash function collision properties) that you're getting the contents you're looking for. Relying on a filename introduces a level of indirection that can serve different contents for the same file. Depending on your use case, that's acceptable or not.

I've considered what you're proposing before as a prefix to a SHA-1 hash. So, something like node1-cd9cf... (the prefix could be anything really, doesn't need to be human readable). This would ensure that all the things with that prefix end up pretty much on a node that identifies itself with an id starting with "node1-". But, you'd have to have a DHT implementation (including k-bucket implementation) that supports variable length ids. In this case, you're guaranteeing a hotspot. It's an equivalent of artificially ensuring that things are "close together" as in the difference between them in the XOR metric is very small. Why would anyone want to do this? For example: com.example.www-cd9cf... combined with some crypto could ensure that while you're participating in a DHT, the data is stored on your servers. I haven't seen this implemented before though.